# If exceed 24 hours show "23:59:59"

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, concatenate

So I got this calculated column called "Due time" with this format in it:

```
=IF([Hours]<24&&[Minutes]<60;CONCATENATE([Hours]&":";[Minutes]);"23:59:59")
```

I only get syntax error with this, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `Hours` and `Minutes` columns are of number type.

Try Using below formula:

```
=IF(AND([Hours]<24, [Minutes]<60); CONCATENATE([Hours], ":", [Minutes]); "23:59:59")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**official documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Sorry  but this doesnt work for me :( Now everything under 23:59:59 gets the timestamp "23:59:59". I would like if its over 23:59:59 it will show that text. So It wont go start counting on the new day again.

Comment: Can you please check adding one item which will have values: Hours less than 24 **And** Minutes less than 60?

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily. It also removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, it's the semi-colons - they should be commas:

```
=IF([Hours]<24&&[Minutes<60,CONCATENATE([Hours]&":",[Minutes]),"23:59:59")
```

Comment: I got european region thing, so I have to use Semi-colons in my format :( Tried with commas also, but doesnt work.